# Google Maps API Webservice usage in windows forms application

Tags: google-maps

My requirement is this.I need to get the latitude and longitude for a given address using Google Maps API. I found in the Google Developers site the following web service which takes address as input and returns so much information of the given site which includes latitude and longitude also. I checked this by executing [this URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Hollywood%20International%20Airport%20%28FLL%29,Fort%20Lauderdale,FL,USA,33315&sensor=false) in the browser.

Latitude and longitude information is coming under geometry/location section. I want to use this web service in windows based application and gets the latitude and longitude of different sites by passing different sites information to this web service each time in a loop.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to either establish a static list of sites to iterate through them and modify the url accordingly or assemble the same url for the site that is requested by the user.

Also, you will need an XML parser:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d83k261.aspx

Comment: Hi,Actually I am not understanding how to use this url in the c# windows application and get the same result which is coming in the browser.In general we add web service url in service reference.But here in my case i need to pass different site addresses to the address parameter of this url. How to do this pro-grammatically?If I can get the same xml result which is coming in the browser after the URL execution,I can be able to parse the result and get the latitude and longitude using xml reader very easily.

Comment: So you have .NET API limitations for windows based applications? Did you try something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744840/invoking-a-url-c-sharp

Comment: Hi,I did the same thing in the link which you are given and solved my problem.I used the HttpWebRequest class and parsed the result and obtained the latitude and longitude of the site.Thanks for your help.